# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Custom Error Page not reachable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, error-handling, razor-pages

I have created a simple `error.cshtml` razor page in the `Pages` folder. `Pages` folder is at the same level as the `Views` folder, so it is at the correct level.

`Error.cshtml` page is similar to the markup and code shown here:

```
@page
<h2>Sorry... Try again later...</h2>
```

In the `Startup.cs` I have the following code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        //app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseNodeModules();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(cfg => {
            cfg.MapControllerRoute("Fallback", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                new { controller = "App", action = "Index" });
        });            
}
```

I made sure that env is not a `Development` environment so it calls `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")`. However when there is an exception is thrown, I get HTTP ERROR 404 "localhost page cannot be found" message instead of getting my custom error page.

I am not sure why my error page is not loading. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I found you don't add the razor page's endpoint mapping setting. This is the reason why you faced the 404 error.

I suggest you could try to add the `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in the  `app.UseEndpoints` method, then it will work well.

Details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

If you don't inject the razor page, you should also add the below codes in the ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddRazorPages();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brando. endpoints.MapRazorPages(); is needed. But I also had to add services.AddRazorPages() to the ConfigureServices(...) in the application startup code.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use RazorPages, you should inject the AddRazorPages in the ConfigureServices method. I guess you already set it, so I don't mention it in the reply. I will edit the reply, If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer, so that other folks who faces the same issue will find the answer more easily.